# What does the index-set mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I encountered this definition of a set from an introductory abstract algebra textbook, I'm confused on what “index-set” means it says: "We say that a set $I$ is an “Index-set” for a collection of sets $\mathcal{A}$ if for any $\mathcal{a}\in{I}$, there exists a set $A_{\mathcal{a}}\in{\mathcal{A}}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{A_{\mathcal{a}}$ | $\mathcal{a}\in{I}\}$. $(I)$ can be any non-empty set, finite or infinite”. From my own understanding $A_{\mathcal{a}}$ acts like, an small-set of ($\mathcal{a}$) in a bigger set $\mathcal{A}$. Am i right?

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is often an index set; for example $\mathcal{A}=$ $\{A_n |$ $ n\in\mathbb N\}$

Comment: It's basically to say that, $A_{n}$ contained on a large set $\mathbb{N}$ or $A_{n}$ is an index set of $\mathbb{N}$ ($\mathcal{A}={A_{n}|n\in{\mathbb{N}}}$) did i get it correctly?

Comment: You want the sets belonging to the familly of sets to be indexed : $A_1, A_2, A_3$ etc.  You therefore need a function from a set of natural numbers to your famlly of sets. The set of indicies ( which is the domain of the function) is the " index set".See Lipschutz, Outline Of Set Theory. ( with, precisely, an index at the end of the book).. In fact, an indexed familly of sets is a function, each " indexed set " is an output of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the phrasing is quite bad, because it should stress on the fact that for all $a\in I$ there is *exactly one* $A_a\in \mathcal A$. In short, saying that $I$ is an indexing set for $\mathcal A$ (or that $\mathcal A$ is indexed by $I$) is tantamount to giving a surjective (but sometimes it is implicitly assumed to be bijective) function $A_{(\bullet)}:I\to\mathcal A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!